# Cors error in dockerised application react nodejs

Tags: reactjs, docker, cors, microservices, same-origin-policy

I made an app which consists of six microservices(nodejs) and a frontend(react). When I run my application from terminal it worked fine. When I dockerise (using compose file) all microservices and the frontend I get cors failed error(same origin policy error). I checked that all microservices and frontend are on the same docker network. I get the error when I try to do a fetch to the backend from the frontend. In the fetch I use the url for example http://localhost:4500/serverUrl and I have exposed the port 4500 in the dockerFile I made for this microservice.Every microservices has a different exposed port.  Has anybody any idea of what I do wrong ? I also have app.use(cors()) in every microservice.

A microservice code:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PUR_CREDITS_SERVER_PORT || 4500;

const purchaseCredits = require('./src/router/purchaseCredits');

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/credits',purchaseCredits);


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Auth Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

dockerFile for this microservice:

```html
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM node:18-alpine

ENV PUR_CREDITS_SERVER_PORT = 4500
ENV ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '61012ba9f763ecdede2423d907840f2ff1e8ac33674c431591247bb8f7bc1e7031226927b1f1d915309b6e538961b0d3752bf918ebbdce34f2ec5620fccf2608'
ENV REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'edbe6c40f3fa0471455720f26b2463366f42970aa39bbc5e4689dbc7c3e6fc254e4891c2d9ca8a403ce9bbb47b3a966b5b931324e8c9d7f2c049524f3cd08da6'

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4500

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

dockerCompose:

```html
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    
    networks:
      - saasNet
  auth:
    build: ./microservices/auth
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - saasNet 
  create-chart:
    build: ./microservices/create chart
    ports:
      - 4001:4001
    networks:
      - saasNet
  download-templates:
    build: ./microservices/download templates
    ports:
      - 4002:4002
    networks:
      - saasNet
  purchase-credits:
    build: ./microservices/purchase credits
    ports:
      - 4500:4500
    networks:
      - saasNet
  user-charts:
    build: ./microservices/user charts
    ports:
      - 4003:4003
    networks:
      - saasNet
  user-info:
    build: ./microservices/user info
    ports:
      - 5000:5000 
    networks:
      - saasNet
  
networks:
  saasNet:
    name: saasNet
    driver: bridge
```

And in frontend i call it here :

```js
async function postCredits(credits){
        if (credits !== 0) {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${state.accessToken}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                },
            };
            const url = `http://localhost:4500/credits/purchaseCredits/${credits}`
            await fetch(url, requestOptions)
                .then((res) => {console.log(res)})
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            console.log(credits);
            //inform the user of the purchase
            toast.info('You bought ' + credits + ' credits!', {
                position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
                hideProgressBar: true
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem you may try this:
First of all install cors
npm install cors

Then in your server file in backend add:

```
   var cors = require('cors')
   app.use(cors())
```

This might help you for this kind of problem

Comment: I have already done that. It does not work:/ it used to work the first time I run it, but then it stopped working. I don't know how this is possible.

Comment: can you attach the code?